# Replace Square-Expression in Maple

Tags: symbolic-math, maple

Given a maple expression like

```
f := (y + 5)^2 + x^2
```

How can I replace all occurrences of the square function with a custom function? The result I want to have would be

```
square(y + 5) + square(x)
```

I tried something like

```
subs({x^2 = square(x)}, f)
```

However, that only replaces the `x^2` expression. I could of course list explicitly the `(y + 5)` term as well, but I want to replace any occurrence of `(.)^2` without listing everything explicitly.

How can I do this in Maple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using either `subsindets` or `applyrule`.

```
expression:=(y-5)^2+3+sin(((z-1/3)^2/(t-(y-s)^2)))+F(f(17+p^2)^2);

                                   /         2  \                 
                                   |  /    1\   |                 
                                   |  |z - -|   |    /          2\
                        2          |  \    3/   |    | / 2     \ |
   expression := (y - 5)  + 3 + sin|------------| + F\f\p  + 17/ /
                                   |           2|                 
                                   \t - (y - s) /                 

applyrule(_a::anything^2=square(_a), expression);

                           /        /    1\  \                               
                           |  square|z - -|  |                               
                           |        \    3/  |
    square(y - 5) + 3 + sin|-----------------| + F(square(f(square(p) + 17)))
                           \t - square(y - s)/                               


subsindets(expression, '`^`'(anything,2), u->square(op(1,u)));

                           /        /    1\  \                               
                           |  square|z - -|  |                               
                           |        \    3/  |                               
    square(y - 5) + 3 + sin|-----------------| + F(square(f(square(p) + 17)))
                           \t - square(y - s)/
```

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. Just one more question, because at the first try the applyrule did not work because I was using the ^ symbol directly, which got replaced by ². That somehow caused maple to enter an infinite loop. When I explicitly wrote ^ out (by using copy-paste), it worked fine. So far I thought there is no difference between ² and ^2, but apparently there is. Do you know anything about this phenomenon as well?

Comment: You're using 2D Input mode, it seems. If you want to do it wirh `applyrule` rather than `subsindets`, then in 2D Input mode use the literal caret for the power instead of the typeset raised power. To get that by typing (rather than copy&paste) you'll need to type the backslash key right before the caret key. Another way would be to put round brackets around `_a::anything`, and then raise that to the power -- typeset or not.